# Why the Smallest Operable Data Type in Most Programming Languages Is One-Byte Sized?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-architecture

Why the smallest operable data type in most programming languages is one-byte sized? Is it possible that to operate with a single bit? If it is possible, how to do it in practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has mostly historical reasons. See [Wikipedia:Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte). Operating on single bits is of course possible. How to do it depends on the programming language. In most languages you have bit level operators for AND, OR, XOR and so forth that you can use to manipulate single bits in a byte. In C you can use bit field structs to define data-types that are (logically) smaller than a byte.

Answer (score 2):

Most instruction sets contain instructions that modify a single byte, but not instruction that modify a single bit and so higher level languages tend to reflect that.

Though modern high level languages include what is effectively a bit type, called boolean. Usually, it can only take two value (true or false), but a boolean requires a whole byte for storage.

If you need to store many bits, what you can do is to use a specialized data structure, which internally uses bytes or integers for storage (and so it stores 8 or more bits in a single underlying element). Such data structures include `std::vector<bool>` in C++ and `BitArray` in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it **is** possible to operate even with single bits on the **processor** level. I would not advise you to do it, since it is way too cumbersome and not universal. E.g., if you really insist to do it for the Intel family, use FLAGS (or, if available, its extensions EFLAGS and RFLAGS).